# Feasibility check command to migrate from On-Premise Active Directory to Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

There is a command to check the compatibility of on-premise active directory to  migrate to Azure Active directory. Could you please let me know the command.

Regards,
Venkat.

Comment: Migration? Or Hybrid? Do you want to use Azure AD DS? Also, I didn't hear about  there is a command to check this compatibility . Can you specify more details of your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing:

> compatibility of on-premise active directory **to migrate** to Azure
>   Active directory

You shall better formulate your question **after** you read about Azure Active Directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis